# How to redirect to a query string URL containing non-ascii characters in DJANGO?

Tags: python, django, unicode, httpresponse

How to redirect to a query string URL containing non-ascii characters in DJANGO?

When I use `return HttpResponseRedirect(u'/page/?title=' + query_string)` where the `query_string` contains characters like `你好`, I get an error

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 21-26: ordinal not
>   in range(128), HTTP response headers must be in US-ASCII format ...

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787935/python-interface-to-paypal-urllib-urlencode-non-ascii-characters-failing

Comment: It's the same problem but that question didn't have a solution either :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
HttpResponseRedirect(((u'/page/?title=' + query_string).encode('utf-8'))
```

is the first thing to try (since UTF8 is the only popular encoding that can handle all Unicode characters).  That should definitely get rid of the exception you're observing -- the issue then moves to ensuring the handler for `/page` can properly deal with UTF-8 encoded queries (presumably by decoding them back into Unicode).  However, that part is not, strictly speaking, germane to this specific question you're asking!

Comment: the chinese character is '\xe4\xbd\xa0' in utf-8... '\xe4', in integer form is "228"... which can't be converted to ascii because its out of range(128). :/ I remember there's a form of representation like &#30001; or something like that, but I can't find any information on it.

There's a post somewhere that makes a passing reference to it: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,22136,22199#msg-22199

Comment: @Eric, when you pass a `str` (an encoded byte string) to `HttpResponseRedirect`, rather than a `unicode` object as you did, there will be no need for Python to try to encode it (with the default `'ascii'` codec) and fail.  So the `\xe4` (and other characters of ord >= 128) will not be a problem!

Comment: OMG I've found the answer, after so many hours... HttpResponseRedirect(urllib.quote_plus((u'/page/?title=' + query_string).encode('utf-8')))

Answer (score 6):

django way:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.utils.http import urlquote

return HttpResponseRedirect(u'/page/?title=%s' % urlquote(query_string))
```